# date-fns issues - Invalid Time Value error message

Tags: reactjs, date, date-fns

My below code is showing the result correctly on console but it's showing error message "invalid time values", do you have any idea what went wrong?

What i'm trying to achieve is to show "how long has the post been posted". For example, it should say "20 minutes ago" on the post.

I'm using date-fns library.

**My Code**

```
const TimeAgo = props => {
  let date = props.date
  let results = new Date(date).toDateString()

  let timesAgo = formatDistanceToNow(new Date(results))
  console.log(timesAgo)
```

**console.log result**

```
  2timeAgo.js:17 about 2 months
    2timeAgo.js:17 3 months
    timeAgo.js:17 4 months
```

Comment: I don't believe there is something wrong with your code. See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-cloud-nnxjzl?file=/src/App.js). There is probably something wrong with your `date` prop.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will have a look at the `date` prop again.